# Unable to separate data with ',' separator while importing text file

Tags: python, pandas, import, delimiter, separator

My data is having a repetitive pattern:

```
2021-11-17 10:59:10.880
SysState: 4, Events: 161403, EMS: 4, VDB: 2, TubeState: 0x02
BDR Mode: 1, BMS Ext: 2, BMS Int: 0, BdrStat: 00
CPU(%):16, CPUmax(%):47, task idx:3, CPUmaxIRQ(%):0
SOC:9973, SOH:100, LV?:0, HV?:0
3330mV 3333mV 3332mV 3332mV 3331mV 0 0
3331mV 3324mV 3325mV 3325mV 3328mV 0 0
3325mV 3321mV 3328mV 3328mV 3327mV 0 0
3329mV 0mV 0mV 0mV 0mV 0 0
BPV:53288, PLV:53241, BPC:0, PLC:0
AMBI:421, CONN:278, FETS:282, BMSC:274, BPA1:259, BPA2:237, BPA3:255
2021-11-17 10:59:13.80
SysState: 4, Events: 161407, EMS: 4, VDB: 3, TubeState: 0x08
BDR Mode: 4, BMS Ext: 3, BMS Int: 1, BdrStat: 00
CPU(%):12, CPUmax(%):47, task idx:3, CPUmaxIRQ(%):0
SOC:9973, SOH:100, LV?:0, HV?:0
3332mV 3331mV 3332mV 3332mV 3331mV 0 0
3331mV 3324mV 3325mV 3326mV 3328mV 0 0
3324mV 3321mV 3328mV 3328mV 3327mV 0 0
3329mV 0mV 0mV 0mV 0mV 0 0
BPV:53288, PLV:53277, BPC:23, PLC:0
AMBI:421, CONN:278, FETS:282, BMSC:276, BPA1:259, BPA2:237, BPA3:255
2021-11-17 10:59:15.280
SysState: 4, Events: 161407, EMS: 4, VDB: 3, TubeState: 0x08
BDR Mode: 4, BMS Ext: 3, BMS Int: 1, BdrStat: 00
CPU(%):11, CPUmax(%):47, task idx:3, CPUmaxIRQ(%):0
SOC:9973, SOH:100, LV?:0, HV?:0
3331mV 3332mV 3331mV 3332mV 3331mV 0 0
3331mV 3324mV 3325mV 3325mV 3328mV 0 0
3324mV 3322mV 3328mV 3328mV 3327mV 0 0
3331mV 0mV 0mV 0mV 0mV 0 0
BPV:53288, PLV:53259, BPC:47, PLC:47
AMBI:421, CONN:278, FETS:282, BMSC:276, BPA1:259, BPA2:237, BPA3:255
```

What I want to do is separate every value and make it a column starting from **'2021-11-17 10:59:10.880'**  to **'BPA3:255'**

| Index | Another header | Another header | Another header |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-11-17 10:59:10.880 | SysState: 4 | Events: 161403 |
| 1 | 2021-11-17 10:59:13.80 | SysState: 4 | Events: 1161407 |

so on and so forth..

what is have done so far:

```
The file was a .txt file and I converted it into csv first and then:

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',' )
```

but it gives me ParserError: Error tokenizing data. Anybody knows how to solve this problem? with the sep= ';' or changing the text file to csv  gives me the following output:

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this while parsing text file and not converting it into csv?

Comment: Your data is not in CSV format. You need to parse that yourself.

Comment: I need to convert it to csv first ? is there any other way ?

Comment: If you plan on using `read_csv`, then your data has to be in CSV format. Otherwise write your own parsing logic for the format.

Comment: But it doesn't work when I convert it to csv as well. Maybe I should mention this in my question.

Comment: In a CSV, each row is supposed to be on one line, is there a repeating pattern? please post a longer excerpt of your input file

Comment: Yes it does. I'll update the input file

Comment: @VaibhavGhildiyal how many columns do you expect as output? only the 3 shown as example?

Comment: @mozway  from '2021-11-17 10:59:10.880' to 'BPA3:255' as shown in the table and then repeat the next row .

Comment: that was not my question I asked about the **columns**, is the example exhaustive? If not, please provide the complete expected output

Comment: @mozway I did. Everything that you want to know is explained clearly in the question. Including the expected output. Please let me know if you still do not understand or I did not understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want only the date, the SysState and Events, an easy way is to extract the info using a regex.

I also assumed the file is not huge so I am loading all in memory, if this is not the case then you'll have to parse line by line.

```
with open('filename.csv') as f:
    lines = f.read()

import re
regex = re.compile('(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d+)\nSysState: (\d+),\s+Events: (\d+).+?')

df = pd.DataFrame(regex.findall(lines), columns=['datetime', 'SysState', 'Events'])
```

*NB. I extracted only the numbers from the fields, but if you really want to have `SysState: 4`, etc. it is easy to add it in the capturing group*

output:

```
                  datetime SysState  Events
0  2021-11-17 10:59:10.880        4  161403
1   2021-11-17 10:59:13.80        4  161407
2  2021-11-17 10:59:15.280        4  161407
```